# Plot a 2D graph from a csv file using matplotlib in Python in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, matplotlib

I have to plot the values from a csv file into graph using python. I am using the follow code in python.
CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph():
    cv,dv = np.loadtxt('/home/test/test_mat.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,axisbg='white')
    plt.plot(x=cv,y=dv)
    plt.title('Chemical Presence')
    plt.ylabel('dv')
    plt.xlabel('cv')
    plt.show()

graph()
```

In the code, I am trying to load the csv file from the location it is present.
The data file looks like the screenshot attached here [data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5i4C.png). Here col 1 = CV (X axis) and row1 = DV ( Y axis).

```
CV\Line        1            2           3           4           5
-7.49952    7.6904296   7.64923087  7.81402579  7.59429923  7.73162833
-7.48388    7.56683341  7.51190177  7.38830558  7.67669669  7.38830558
-7.46824    7.03124992  7.38830558  7.49816886  7.51190177  7.66296378
-7.4526     7.53936759  7.66296378  7.71789542  7.62176505  7.6904296
-7.43696    7.49816886  7.73162833  7.45697013  7.71789542  7.38830558
-7.42132    7.01751701  7.20977775  7.48443595  7.58056632  7.81402579
-7.40568    7.58056632  7.71789542  7.70416251  7.49816886  7.58056632
```

But I am getting an error while executing the code.The following is the error:

ERROR:
    File "/home/kishore/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 928, in loadtxt items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

```
File "/home/kishore/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 659, in floatconv
return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: CV\Line
```

I am new to Python programming. can anyone please help me in knowing how to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the necessary changes as you suggested. A new error has come up as mentioned below                                                                                                       "File "test.py", line 5, in graph
    cv,dv = np.loadtxt(open('/home/kishore/test/test_mat.csv'),delimiter=',', skiprows=1,unpack=True)
ValueError: too many values to unpack ".   The reason for too many values is that the data file actually contains 54 columns and 961 rows of entries. how can I overcome this error message ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we should escape out the spaces in the path to make certain that it isn't choking on that:

```
cv,dv = np.loadtxt('/home/kishore/Documents/Owlstone\ developer\ task\ briefing/test_matrix.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
```

or, change your directory name to have no spaces, e.g. `Owlstone`.

Alternatively, you could move the file and the script into the same directory and remove all the path information to prove that all is well with actually finding the file n the first place. It is clear from your error output that you are not getting past this line, so concentrate there first.

Now past the escaped space potential, let's concentrate on what is in the file. Your image and your posted data are not using `,` as a delimiter. Fixing that and using as data

```
-7.49952,7.6904296,7.64923087,7.81402579,7.59429923,7.73162833
-7.48388,7.56683341,7.51190177,7.38830558,7.67669669,7.38830558
-7.46824,7.03124992,7.38830558,7.49816886,7.51190177,7.66296378
-7.4526,7.53936759,7.66296378,7.71789542,7.62176505,7.6904296
-7.43696,7.49816886,7.73162833,7.45697013,7.71789542,7.38830558
-7.42132,7.01751701,7.20977775,7.48443595,7.58056632,7.81402579
-7.40568,7.58056632,7.71789542,7.70416251,7.49816886,7.58056632
```

where I have removed the first row (rather than `skiprows=1` as suggested above, since that doesn't fix the `Too many values to unpack` problem) I can get an array via

```
dv = np.loadtxt('text.csv', delimiter=',')
print(dv)
```

yielding

```
[[-7.49952     7.6904296   7.64923087  7.81402579  7.59429923  7.73162833]
 [-7.48388     7.56683341  7.51190177  7.38830558  7.67669669  7.38830558]
 [-7.46824     7.03124992  7.38830558  7.49816886  7.51190177  7.66296378]
 [-7.4526      7.53936759  7.66296378  7.71789542  7.62176505  7.6904296 ]
 [-7.43696     7.49816886  7.73162833  7.45697013  7.71789542  7.38830558]
 [-7.42132     7.01751701  7.20977775  7.48443595  7.58056632  7.81402579]
 [-7.40568     7.58056632  7.71789542  7.70416251  7.49816886  7.58056632]]
```

N.B.: You can prove that things are working in general by including the following either in the console or in your code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
c = StringIO("-7.49952,7.6904296,7.64923087,7.81402579,7.59429923,7.73162833\n-7.48388,7.56683341,7.51190177,7.38830558,7.67669669,7.38830558")
print(np.loadtxt(c, delimiter=","))
```

and you will see a nice array as well.

Now to plot we are going to work with the data presented, and we have `(X,Y)` pairs of the form `(col2, col1)` for the matrix, so the first two values to be plotted are `(7.6904296, -7.49952)` and `(7.56683341, -7.48388)` and we are disregarding the remainder of each row, columns 3-6, originally labelled as `2,3,4,5`.

```
def graph():
    dv = np.loadtxt('text.csv', delimiter=',')
    print(dv)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    x = dv[:,1]
    y = dv[:,0]
    ax.scatter(x,y)
    plt.title('Chemical Presence')
    plt.ylabel('CV')
    plt.xlabel('DV')
    plt.show()
```

The notation here of `dv[:,0]` is subsetting the array `dv` with all the rows and only the values of column 0, with the general format being `array[rows,columns]`. This code gives us

[image: Chemical Presence Plot]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have simplified the path of the file and script into a single folder. Still I get the same error. I am wondering if I should try to add a converter to read the float values in the data file ?

Comment: I have mentioned a fraction of the data file content in the question

Comment: I don't want to have to type it in! Please paste some text so that we can recreate your problem. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/).

Comment: I have included the data in the code as you requested.

Comment: thank you for your response. what about selecting few values from the file and try to plot them. In this case how to represent the data in code ?

Comment: sure, but you have to explain the data. Your header indicated that you have 6 columns of data, first called `CV/Line` and the others `1,2,3,4,5`. I suspect that this isn't correct, but I don't know, it's your data. What would you want plotted out of a `7x6` array of floats?

Comment: The data I posted in question is just a fraction of whole data. the actual file contains 54 columns and 961 rows in total. I would not be possible for me to post all of them so I gave a sample of it

Comment: Yes. I need to plot the float values in the graph.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that. This is proving unfruitful and we need to move this to chat.

Comment: I am not able to move to chat since I have less reputation to do so.

Comment: No....I still can't respond to this link as I don't have minimum of 20 reputations. I am really sorry for it. can you please create a new answer for this question and put your comments there...

Comment: Ugh. I have posted a question to meta on how to get around this, but, sadly, in the meanwhile, let's plough on. You have a 7x6 array, with a header that listed the columns as `CV/Line, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. You want a scatterplot I think. So what points are being plotted? What are the (x,y) pairs? all we have are vectors with 6 values, e.g., `[-7.48388     7.56683341  7.51190177  7.38830558  7.67669669  7.38830558]`. Those are all the y values for `x=1,2,3,4,5` or what? You only have an array of floats, you don't have dimensioned data to plot...yet.

Comment: The data I posted in question is just a fraction of whole data. the actual file contains 54 columns and 961 rows in total. I would not be possible for me to post all of them so I gave a sample of it. The first column floating point values are the X axis and the first row with numbers 1,2,3,4,5.....are the X-axis values. the other floating point values are the points that should be plotted based on X-axis and Y-axis.

Comment: Nope, still don't follow. I am not worried about how much other data you have. That isn't relevant. Let's contain our enthusiasm for the data posted here. Here are the first two rows of your data. `[-7.49952     7.6904296   7.64923087  7.81402579  7.59429923  7.73162833]
 [-7.48388     7.56683341  7.51190177  7.38830558  7.67669669  7.38830558]`. In your original post, please show us how those relate to X,Y values. Write something like `x=col1, y=col2` and `x=col1, y=col3`. Or write out some (x,y) pairs with your numbers if you can't manage that. But shift it to your OP, please.

Comment: now please check and let me know if you can understand.

Comment: thank you Shawn for your response. I now could reach to a conclusive point. But I have one clarification. In your comment above the graph, you have mentioned x = dv[:,1]   y = dv[:,0]. what exactly does these two lines do ??

Comment: Yes....though I could generate a graph by making few changes to the graph which is to some extent answers the task. can you please help in knowing the answer for my question in previous comment.

Comment: I did. The answer has been edited. That's what I meant when I asked "did that help you?". Read just above the final plot...